# How to use a C++ requires clause in a concept to require a member variable to satisfy a concept constraint?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, c++-concepts

I was watching a [C++ 20 Concepts Presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qawSiMIXtE4&t=2726s)  , and when attempting to reproduce the code I seem to be stuck.

I am trying to require that the root of the tree should satisfy the MyObjConcept0_, which for simplicity's sake is just an int. How come when I use this concept in the requires clause of the Tree_ concept the results are false?

I tried to copy the code directly from the presentation and still no luck. Why is the return type of the { t.root } clause an int& - I mean it makes sense, because when you access a member that way you get a reference.

So how come in the presentation at 39:00 this(same as MyObjConcept0_) requires clause passes?

Did something change in the standard from the point of this presentation or am I blindly missing something?

```
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>

// Type is an int
template<typename T>
concept MyObjConcept0_ = std::same_as<T,int>;

// Type is any type that decays to int
template<typename T>
concept MyObjConcept1_ = std::same_as<std::decay_t<T>,int>;

// Type is an int&
template<typename T>
concept MyObjConcept2_ = std::same_as<T,int&>;



template<typename T>
concept Tree_ = requires (T t) {
    { t.root } -> MyObjConcept0_;          // does not work : This is the concept I want to use  
    { t.root } -> MyObjConcept1_;          // works but will pass for int and int& : unsafe
    { t.root } -> MyObjConcept2_;          // works but checks that t.root is an int&
    std::same_as<decltype(t.root),int>; // works: verbose and not a concept
};

template<MyObjConcept0_ MyObjConcept0T>
struct tree {
    MyObjConcept0T root;
};

static_assert(Tree_<tree<int>>);
```

Answer (score 8):

The *compound-requirement*

```
{ e } -> Concept;
```

means that `e` must be a valid expression and `Concept<decltype((e))>` must hold. Note the double parentheses, this is important. Let's just take a simpler tree, I don't know why this needs to be a template:

```
struct X {
    int root;
};

X t;
```

While `decltype(t.root)` is `int` (the declared type of that member variable is `int`), `decltype((r.root))` is `int&` (because it is an lvalue of type `int`, hence `int&`). As a result:

```
template <typename T>
concept Tree = requires(T t) {
    { t.root } -> std::same_as<int&>;
};
```

`Tree<X>` holds - because `t.root` is an lvalue of type `int`.

---

clang simply gets this wrong. It does not implement [P1084](https://wg21.link/p1084), this is [#45088](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45088).

Comment: So this answer is unfortunately incorrect as it will also satisfy the concept if the t.root type is an int&. Compiled on GCC 10.2. 
struct tree_intref { int& root; }; // Shouldnt satisfy tree concept

Comment: @BigTeeny The answer is correct - you're just asking a different question now. If you want to check the _specific type_ of a member, you cannot use a _compound-requirement_, you just have to write `requires same_as<decltype(T::root), int>`.

Comment: Thank you, I see my mistake now. I will reformat the question better as it seems the focus seemed on the int type, as opposed to passing a concept as a requirement to a non static class member in a compound-requirement clause as shown in the presentation at 39:00.

Comment: Also to add, according to https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx20 , Concepts P1084R2 is available from clang 10.

Comment: @BigTeeny Well, that status is incorrect, given that the implementation does the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Requirements check types of *expressions*. In order to assess the type of a *variable*, you have to check an expression that encodes `decltype` of your variable.

```
template <typename T>
struct wrap{};

// member declared as `int`
{ wrap<decltype(t.intv)>() } -> std::same_as<wrap<int>>;

// member declared as `int&`
{ wrap<decltype(t.intlrefv)>() } -> std::same_as<wrap<int&>>;

// member declared as `int&&`
{ wrap<decltype(t.intrrefv)>() } -> std::same_as<wrap<int&&>>;
```

Comment: This solution works on GCC 10.2 and Clang 10.0 but I have to specify the type int explicitly. I want to pass another concept as a constraint on the member variable t.root not an explicit type.

Comment: Something like this (pseudocode) :
template <typename T>
concept Tree_ = requires(T t) {
    { Wrapper<decltype(t.root)>() } -> std::same_as<Wrapper<Node_>>;
};

Comment: The `wrap` adds a lot of typing but... why? Just write `requires std::same_as<decltype(t.intv), int>;`?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all or your answers, they pointed me in the right direction but they were not generic enough form my problem. As the key problem was passing a concept type to the requires clause of another concept. I should-of specified that.

After couple hours on compiler explorer I figured out a solution.
Working in clang 10.0.0 and up with -std=c++20 :

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>


template<typename T>
concept Node_ = std::is_object_v<T>; 

template<typename T>
concept Tree_ = requires (T t) {
    { t.root } -> Node_;
    /* implement child tuple constraints here */
};

// Generic tree object 
template<Node_ NodeT /*, Tree_ ... ChildrenT*/>
struct tree {
    NodeT root;
    /* implement child tuple here */
};

struct test_tree_int { int root; }; // Should satisfy tree concept
struct test_tree_intref { int& root; }; // Shouldnt satisfy tree concept


static_assert(Tree_<tree<int>>);
static_assert(Tree_<test_tree_int>);
//static_assert(Tree_<test_tree_intref>); /// Compilation fails
```

And the reason why this didn't work for me earlier is because I was using GCC 10.2 which does in-fact have the compiler issue mentioned by Barry: the double parentheses in Concept<decltype((e))> produces a reference.

Seems like all the solutions will increase code bloat which will make using the concepts more of a hassle than help.

Comment: As I stated in my answer, this is _not correct_. `test_tree_int` does _not_ satisfy `Tree` (neither does `test_tree_intref`... in fact, no type can). It's not that gcc has a "compiler issue" - gcc is correct, that is the language rule. It's clang that is wrong here.

Comment: Thanks for your time I'm clearly misunderstanding something, just to confirm if possible. The code shown in the presentation(at 39:00 - 40:00, it is the same) is not valid? I am trying my best to emulate that exact system but to no avail. Sadly no source code for that presentation is available.

Comment: Finally found the source: https://github.com/saarraz/slides/blob/master/cppcon2019-concepts-a-day-in-the-life/code.cpp , at line #62. You can see this exact use of the requires statement. Compiles on clang not gcc.

Comment: Yes. Again, it compiles on clang because clang incorrectly implements the language rule. `{ t.root } -> Node` means `Node<decltype((t.root))>`, not `Node<decltype(t.root)>` - and as such, no type can ever satisfy `Tree`.